# Client-server authentication protocol suggestion

Tags: authentication

I'm designing an authentication methods for my client/server system consisting of:

- a windows desktop client application (.NET)
- windows/linux servers (C++)
- one "security server" which authorizes the users and passes
  some tokens for single sign on to the other servers

A user would login providing username and a password to the security server with I think a simple hashing password + salt or some challenge-response algorithm. On successful login the returned auth token the user could present to the server that would automatically authenticate them.

Note: I know that I could just use SSL, but I would like to (for some reasons)
Note2: The communication doesn't need to be encrypted by default (it would be in "half" trusted environment)

What I have found that the Kerberos looks quite similiar and it it seems that my security server would be a simplified Kerberos server.

I think I would need:

- authenication protocol (client-security server)
- algorithm for token generation and its verification

Any suggestions? Where to start?

Comment: "I know that I could just use SSL, but I would like to (for some reasons)" - What does that mean?  Did you leave out some words?  What would you like to?  And what are the reasons?  The first question a security professional is probably going to ask is: why not just use SSL?  I encourage you to edit the question to make this clearer, if you'd like to get useful responses.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The main reason I don't want SSL is the performance - which has a bigger priority for me. I know that making my own security won't beat SSL's but as I said before: the system will run on intranet so security has lower priority than a performance.

Comment: Have you benchmarked the performance of SSL?  There are a lot of misconceptions and myths about the performance overhead of SSL; SSL can perform quite well.  See, e.g., https://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html